# How to animate the edge of a view in Android?

Tags: android, animation, view

I have an `ImageView` on my UI, I want to animate its left edge moving right: the image itself stay unmoved, but its left part becomes invisible, showing the view underneath. (Think negative margin in CSS).

[image]

How can I achieve this?

What I want actually is the Before-After effect like this:
https://zurb.com/playground/twentytwenty

My plan is to stack 2 imageViews, when I animate the edge of imageView on the top, the imageView below is partially revealed.

Ideas other than animating the edge is also fine, as long as I can get the effect.

Comment: just put a black view above ImageVIew, and move it in from left covering a part of ImageView with it

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko That's not a back view, it's the view underneath the image.

Comment: if it would be under the image, then how could you see it then?

Comment: Oh, now I got it, let me give another idea

Comment: You can place that background view in some container in foreground, and change the container width from 0 to whatever you need, while you change the negative right margin of the view inside the container for the same value

Comment: use `android.graphics.drawable.ClipDrawable` - *"A Drawable that clips another Drawable based on this Drawable's current level value. You can control how much the child Drawable gets clipped in width and height based on the level, as well as a gravity to control where it is placed in its overall container."*

Answer (score 3):

first, you need to create resize animation which makes the view size change like this

note this is a Kotlin code and it is hight change if you need width you need to replace the view

```
 class ResizeAnimation(var view: View, val targetHight: Int) : Animation() {
    val startWidth: Int = view.height

     override fun applyTransformation(interpolatedTime: Float, t: Transformation) {
        val newHight = (startWidth + (targetHight - startWidth) * interpolatedTime).toInt()
        view.layoutParams.height = newHight
        view.requestLayout()
    }


    override fun willChangeBounds(): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}
```

next in your activity call it like any another animation example

```
val anime = ResizeAnimation(view, commentViewHight)
            anime.duration = 250
            anime.fillAfter =true
            view.startAnimation(anime)
```

**since you deal with image view Like the example above change the scale type in your image to "fit end"**

note you cannot use this code in `oncreate()` you need to make sure that the view is visible first to calculate your height/width

Comment: Animating height/width doesn't seem to work with "FIT_END" mode, the image gets squeezed into a corner, not clipped. Animating `clipBounds` seems to work, though.